# Optimum / limit daily dose of Vitamin C?

Tags: nutrition, micronutrients

The National Institutes of Health's Office of Dietary Supplements [states](https://ods.od.nih.gov/factsheets/VitaminC-Consumer/#h2) that the recommended daily amount of Vitamin C for an adult male is 90 mg. The highest recommended dose is 120 mg for breastfeeding women. The [upper limit](https://ods.od.nih.gov/factsheets/VitaminC-Consumer/#h8) does of Vitamin C for adults is 2,000 mg.

The book "Prescription for Natural Healing" (5th ed.), however, recommends an optimum daily intake of 1,000 to 3,000 mg of "Vitamin C with mineral ascorbates (Ester-C)". I don't have much experience with the book and I'm trying to gauge how helpful it is.

Am I right to see a conflict here? Or are they talking about different things? Is this really as simple as the book making a wildly bad recommendation, or is there reason to think a higher dose is good?

Comment: @David I'm not asking anyone to read the book - I'm just curious if there is indeed a conflict here or if I'm missing a distinction somewhere.

Comment: There is a conflict; the NIH is not trying to get you to spend lots of money in the alt-health business.  The book is.

Comment: I edited your question to remove the link to Amazon. If someone wants to buy the book I'm sure they can find it without a direct link here.

Comment: @CareyGregory thanks - I didn't mean to suggest that people buy it. I was just clearly indicating what book I was talking about.

Comment: You will get different numbers from different sources on many nutritional recommendations.   Read the reason for the high number and determine for yourself if you consider it credible.

Answer (score 6):

Here are few aspects of high-dose vitamin C supplements.

**The upper limit(UL)** 2,000 mg for vitamin C is not some sort of recommendation, but a dose, which, if exceeded, can cause nausea and diarrhea, for example.

**Does it make sense to take vitamin C supplements?**

Vitamin C supplements can correct vitamin C deficiency and improve the absorption of iron from plant foods. But there is no convincing evidence that vitamin C would help to prevent or treat common cold, cancer, heart disease, stroke or age-related macular degeneration.

**Are higher doses more effective?**

Approximately 70%–90% of vitamin C is absorbed at moderate intakes of 30–180 mg/day. However, **at doses above 1 g/day, absorption falls to less than 50%** and absorbed, unmetabolized ascorbic acid is excreted in the urine.

There is no convincing evidence that high-dose (oral) vitamin C would prevent or treat cancer or other diseases.

**Can high-dose vitamin C be dangerous?**

High-dose vitamin C might increase the risk of oxalate kidney stones in some individuals.

Reference:
https://ods.od.nih.gov/factsheets/VitaminC-HealthProfessional/